# Динамически создавать форму ответа на комментарии

Tags: javascript, форма

Добрый день, помогите пожалуйста сделать форму ответа на комментарии, я в php разбираюсь, а вот с js полнейший 0.
Ситуация такая, в цикле выводятся комментарии и под каждым комментарием кнопка ответить, нужно при нажатии под ней динамически создать форму под комментарием в которой будет input (имя) и textarea (содержимое) и кнопка ответить, ну и скрытый инпут с id комментария на который отвечаем.
Я знаю как сделать не динамически, а через display:none, но этот способ мне крайне не нравится, генерить по 10 форм на странице как о не нормально.
Заранее большое спасибо за помощь!

Comment: через jQuery или native JS?

Comment: Наверное лучше через jQuery, через нее наверное будет удобнее и проще.
(Но точно ответить не могу т.к. не разбираюсь в js)

Comment: наверное всё-таки стоит разобраться, т.к. если здесь будет готовый код, который не так уж и сложен, то толку от него будет только для вашей конкретной задачи, а в десятке аналогичных ситуаций вы снова обратитесь сюда

Comment: Уже 10 июля записан на курсы js, на работе всегда не могу выделить время на обучения, а дома семья - там времени еще меньше, по этому только на курсах могу научится....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примерно **[так](http://jsfiddle.net/urTCt/3/)**, но я очень рекомендую ознакомится с js и с [jQuery](http://www.rsdn.ru/article/inet/jQuery.xml)

> сделать чтобы при нажатии на кнопку add, она заменялась на close. И чтобы если тыкаешь по другому add, предыдущий закрывался

обновил ответ, использовал классы для хранения состояния, но впредь пытайтесь делать самостоятельно

- **[.hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)**
- **[.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)**
- **[.removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)**
- **[.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)**

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно, сейчас попробую прикрутить все это дело к себе.

Comment: добавил работу со скрытым полем

Comment: Spectre, прошу еще раз прощения, но не подскажете как сделать чтобы при нажатии на кнопку add, она заменялась на close.
И чтобы если тыкаешь по другому add, предыдущий закрывался, а этот(новый) открывался, сейчас тыкаешь сначала закрывается старый, второй раз тыкаешь открывается новый.
Заранее большущее спасибо!

Comment: БОЛЬШУЩЕЕ СПАСИБО!!!